# How can I bring correct date format in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

So, I'm trying to automate some dates in VBA. I get date, month and year separately and concatenate all three in one cell in VBA. But with this approach, I get date like "unformatted" and cannot filter them in months. Excel treats them like "text"

In attached screenshot, you can see bottom 4 cells which I actually refreshed by hitting F2 and enter. This updates them into date format and filter treats them as "date"

How can I automate this so that only in VBA, I can put them in this format?

The code is as follows

```
    'for each row run a formula to concatenate G+F+H for DD/MM/YYYY
    For Cnt = 2 To Cnt2
    
        If Cells(Cnt, 7).Value > 12 Then
            Cells(Cnt, 9).Value = Cells(Cnt, 7).Value & "." & Cells(Cnt, 6).Value & "." & Cells(Cnt, 8).Value
        Else
            Cells(Cnt, 9).Value = Cells(Cnt, 6).Value & "." & Cells(Cnt, 7).Value & "." & Cells(Cnt, 8).Value
            
        End If
            
    Next Cnt
    
    'delete F G H columns
    Columns("F:H").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
    
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d/m/yy"
```

[image]

Comment: Create "real" dates, then format them.  Use the vba `Dateserial` function to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DateSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) instead of concatenating:

```
Cells(Cnt, 9).Value = DateSerial(Cells(Cnt, 8).Value, Cells(Cnt, 6).Value, Cells(Cnt, 7).Value)
```

Comment: This has solve my problem without and similar statement :) Many thanks BigBen

Answer (score 0):

try using this code, please configure all as you need

Good Luck

```
'Copy all code
'This is the configurable part
    Private Const _
    MyFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy", _
    MySheet = "Test", _
    MyFirstRangeCell = "F1"
'This is the configurable part

   'This dont need move anything
Function MyFormatDay(d_ As String, m_ As String, y_ As String) As String
    MyFormatDay = Format(DateSerial(y_, m_, d_), MyFormat)
End Function

'this dont need to move so much, maybe nothing
Sub GetDates()
    Sheets(MySheet).Select
    Range(MyFirstRangeCell).Select
    Do While ActiveCell <> ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = MyFormatDay(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1),    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop


End Sub


'Copy all code
```

Comment: Your strangely named arguments `x_` should be declared as Integer.